# php delete specific value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$products` that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [services] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [icon] => bus.png
                    [name] => Web Development
                    [cost] => 500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [icon] => icon.png
                    [name] => Icon design
                    [cost] => 300
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to delete the part of array that matches `[id] => 1` and for this I am using the following code

```
$key = array_search('1', $products);
unset($products['services'][$key]);
```

However it is not working and I am not getting any error either.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you only want to delete [id] => 1 from that subarray, or the whole parent array (with key 0 in this case) ?

Comment: foreach is the way to go

Comment: @edwardmp I would like to delete the whole parent array (with key 0 in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$key = array_search('1', $products["services"]);
                                //^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here i search in this array
unset($products['services'][$key]);

print_r($products);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [services] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [icon] => icon.png [name] => Icon design [cost] => 300 ) ) )
```

And if you want to reindex the array, so that it starts again with 0 you can do this:

```
$products["services"] = array_values($products["services"]);
```

Then you get the output:

```
Array ( [services] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [icon] => icon.png [name] => Icon design [cost] => 300 ) ) )
                            //^^^ See here starts again with 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This will loop through `$products['services']` and delete the array whose `'id'` key has value 1.  `array_values` just re-indexes the array from 0 again.

```
foreach($products['services'] as $key => $service)
{
    if($product['id'] == 1)
    {
        unset($products['services'][$key]);
        array_values($products['services']);
        break;
    }
}
```